# Do I need to use "using" keyword in every object which implements IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using-statement

I am calling a 3rd party library, where so many class implemented IDisposable.

Do I need to use using pattern on all of them?

Comment: Dispose should definitely be called on objects that you 'own' (you've created with `new` or a factory method) before the objects go out of scope. A `using` block is an easy way to achieve this.

Comment: It's the desirable pattern. If you do this way, you'll be sure all underlying resources which aren't controlled by you are correctly released. Why not?

Comment: No, but if you don't then you need to make sure that you dispose of them and all resources that they own.

Comment: This is a very good question, and one that I've only come to which I've only come to understand the answer as a more advanced .NET developer.  You'd think something like this would be more explicitly defined, but it's really not.

Comment: I don't know why someone converted my answer to comment.

Answer (score 5):

You don't **have** to, but it is good practice.

It ensures resources are cleaned up properly whether exceptions occur or not.

`IDisposable` should only be implemented on classes that need to cleanup resources, so ensuring that they do is good practice.

There may be cases that calling `Dispose` directly instead of a using block will be required (WCF proxies are notorious for this), but this is not the general case.

In short - no one will force you to use them, but you really really should.

Comment: @Odded I'm not that sure "no one is forced to[...]" about **using** statement. I'd like to argue that it **must be used** if some code block takes advantage of some class and this implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - I am just saying that there is no `using` police force to enforce the usage of `using` on `IDisposable`. Perhaps I am wrong and there is one in Spain ;)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - by the way, it's `Oded`, not `Odded`.

Comment: @Odded Absolutely, Spain has it!! ;) There's no police forcing this, but why that risk? Or why a try/catch/finally if there's a nice syntactic sugar? :D

Comment: Ops, sorry, @Oded, I did it twice. Sorry.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - Of course I agree that it _should_ be used. That's not the question though.

Comment: Haha, ok, btw, I said Spain has it, so I'll keep using _using_ because I don't want to have problems... j/k

Comment: May I suggest an additional note that there are cases where you would want to call Dispose() explicitly instead of using a using block?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - By all means, add one :)

Comment: Because I'm on mobile, it's hard for me to format code items properly. Plus, I can be verbose, and your answer concludes with "in short" :D

Answer (score 3):

You don't “need” to do it, but you most likely should.

If you don't do that, you can be running out of some resources, or you can even get incorrect results, depending on what exactly does that library do.

But without knowing what exactly does `Dispose()` do on those objects, you should definitely call it, to avoid unexpected problems. (And you don't have to do that directly, you can use `using` to do that, as you suggested.)

Answer (score 3):

That depends very much on the scope of the variable in question.

### Local Scope: using

If the variable is scoped locally, yes, you should enclose relevant code in a `using` block.  Remember, a `using` block is just syntax sugar for the following, assuming `using` is enclosing an IDisposable object named `obj`:

```
var obj = // ...
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    obj.Dispose();
}
```

This means that even if an exception is thrown, your object will be disposed.

### Class Scope: IDisposable

If your object is scoped at a class level, then no, you should not be enclosing it in a `using` block.  Rather, your class should expose the `Dispose` method to any code that uses it by implementing `IDisposable`, and dispose the object there.

### Never Use: Finalize

Generally, it is bad practice to transfer disposal responsibility to the garbage collector at any point in this dependency chain by relying on a class's finalizer to dispose its objects.  This undermines this difference between `Dispose` and `Finalize`: `Dispose` is for explicit, immediate resource release, while `Finalize` is more passive.  By relying on `Finalize` to call `Dispose`, you undermine this separation of purpose.  However, this is more a matter of programming style on my part, and represents an opinion--do not take it as a fact.  You should research this more on your own--and certainly read the inevitable array of incoming comments on the matter--before taking my advice.  I'm sure I missed important exceptions, at the very least.

Comment: You mentioned something many others seem to have missed here: you sometimes want to explicitly call Dispose() instead of using a using block.

Comment: And before you all go saying "Finalize, oh, that's Java, not C#," the destructor in .NET is often referred to by the name `Finalize`.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Yes, that's why I continued posting my answer even after so many others had been posted.  Sometimes--many times--explicitly calling `Dispose` is better.  `using` just doesn't make sense for class-scoped variables.

Comment: @Zenexer: It's not just "often referred to by the name `Finalize`".  If a class overrides `Object.Finalize()`, the object will not be garbage-collected until after that method has been called or `GC.SuppressFinalize()` is used to indicate it's not necessary.  Since nearly every program that uses a C# destructor properly (a destructor being a syntactic unit that requests the compiler to override `Object.Finalize`) must include a call `GC.SuppressFinalize()`, the term "finalize" seems far more apropos than "destructor", though the latter term is still necessary to describe the C# wrapper.

Comment: @supercat I know there are a lot of reasons that `Finalize` is most appropriate (which is why I used it), but a you'd be surprised how many people scream "Java!" when they hear it.  Very good explanation, though.

Answer (score 0):

When a class implements IDisposable it is saying that it would rather be disposed by your code than wait for the garbage collector to dispose it at a later time. So yes, if a class implements IDisposable you should call Dispose (or use using) before it goes out of scope.

Should you use using instead of calling Dispose directly? Again, yes. To ensure that an object is disposed you would have to make sure your objects were disposed even if an exception was thrown, by encapsulating your code in a try { ... } finally {} block that would dispose your objects in the finally block. This leads to unnecessary clutter and you can easily forget to add the finally block.

It is much safer to use using for this job.